# Don't trigger action on pushing new branch to remote

Tags: github, github-actions

I have set up an action to be triggered on *every* push, but *its steps* to exit if the commit message *doesn't* conform to a specific pattern. This commit basically points to a new release, and occurs only on the `master` branch.

However, when after a new release, a new branch is forked from master and pushed to origin *without any further commits*, that action is triggered again.

Is there any way to specify that the action should not be triggered on pushing a new branch, but rather only fresh commits?

Workflow snippet:

```
name: Release APK
on: push

jobs:
  build:
    if: "contains(github.event.head_commit.message, 'apkRelease@@')"
    name: Build APK

<...trimmed rest of the yaml>
```

With this, when say commit C with message "apkRelease@@ver123" is pushed in `master` to correspond to a new release, the Build APK step would be triggered. But then if I fork a new `dev` branch and push it to origin without any commits, the action and step will be triggered again. This I want to prevent.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you should just filter for master branch since you're looking at the head commit message to know when to run your step. This means this workflow will only be triggered when merging a commit to master branch so even if a new user creates a different branch then it won't run as it doesn't match the branch filter.

```
on:
  push:
    branches:    
      - master
jobs:
  build:
    if: "contains(github.event.head_commit.message, 'apkRelease@@')"
    name: Build APK
```

Comment: I cant fix a branch unfortunately.